# Microsoft wants to install updates for a different OS version

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-update

I was looking at the specifics for the latest Microsoft security updates on the Microsoft website.
I noticed that it was proposed to install updates *tagged* for a different OS version from the one I have.

For example, I have Windows 7 64-bit and one of the *Important updates* proposed is the [KB3057154](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3057154).
On the Microsoft website it is said that the supported OS version is Windows 8.

So my questions are, why is Microsoft saying this is an important update for my system when I don't have that OS version, and is it really necessary for me to install this or any other updates not specifically targeted for my OS?

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand.  You are asking the reason, Windows Update is offering you `KB3057154`, is that correct?

Comment: Nooooooooo... I'm asking why they're offering me updates for an OS version that I don't have. Seems very clear to me.

Comment: The specific update you asked about, also was released on Windows 7, if the question is not about [KB3057154](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3057154) you should clarify your question.  If it isn't about [KB3057154](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3057154), I am not going to be happy, I just spent 20 minutes writing an answer about [KB3057154](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3057154) because you specifically called it out and indicated your incorrect belief it was only for Windows 8.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you are being offered [KB3057154](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3057154.aspx) on Windows 7, is because Windows 7, is one of the affected versions of Windows.

Here is the full description of the update

> Microsoft is announcing
> the availability of an update to harden scenarios in which Data
> Encryption Standard (DES) encryption keys are used with accounts.
> Microsoft disabled DES by default starting in **Windows 7** and **Windows
> Server 2008 R2**. However, this update provides enhanced user protection
> in environments where DES is still enabled for application
> compatibility reasons. The improvement is part of ongoing efforts to
> bolster the effectiveness of encryption in Windows.
>
> This update by default disables DES for the following built-in accounts:
>
> krbtgt account
>
> trust accounts
>
> machine accounts
>
> machine accounts\user accounts
>
> Machine accounts\user accounts may be set to enable “Use DES” if required.
>
> For additional details and deployment guidance, see [Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 3057154](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3057154).

Here is a screenshot of the affected system(s).

[image]

Here are the download links if you need them.

[image]

[Download Windows 7 SP1 32-bit (3057154)](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=cfd03853-1f6c-4de3-a6bd-d405546d23ab)

[Download Windows 7 SP1 64-bit (3057154)](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0b3c4d4d-3fc8-4936-9b00-299aac7f3e73)

[Microsoft Security Advisory 3057154](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3057154)

[Microsoft security advisory: Update to harden use of DES encryption: July 14, 2015](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3057154.aspx)

Comment: First of all KB3057154 was used as an example, I specifically used the word "example" in my post. But thanks for the info, it's helpful. Moving on, if you click on "System Requirements" on this Microsoft link >>> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47769&WT.mc_id=rss_windows_allproducts <<< Windows 7 isn't mentioned, only Windows 8. If the update is relevant to my OS then they need to list ALL the OSs the update is meant for.

Comment: @MichaelSwartz - So you use an example, that applies to Windows 7 and Windows 8.0, and are then shocked its confusing?  You linked to the [Windows 8](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47769), KB3057154 download, but KB3057154 is a [multi-operating system update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3057154).  There is a [Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47778) download page by the way.  If you want a more specific response, clarify your question, be very specific about the exact update you believe you should not be getting.

Comment: Feel free to take a picture of the incorrect update being offered in Windows Update and post the url to the image.  If my answer needs to be adjusted I will do so, of course, I have answered the question that was asked.